# Creating A Database through PHP with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a web app to allow database creation though, I want to restrict the creation to one database per user , also i have not yet implemented any security at this point my concern is the logic. I will implement security after I have the correct logic. So please give advice on the logic.

1. I am looking for advice to see how I can improve this script. It is functional and does work at this point.

   ```
       //define connection
       $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','XXXXX','billing');

       //Variables
       $UserEmail = $_SESSION['email'];
       $MysqlUserDataBaseCreate = $_POST['create_database'];

       //CheckIfUserExists
       $SeeIfUserExist = "SELECT * FROM database_users WHERE email='$UserEmail';";
       $SqlQueryUserCheck = mysqli_query($conn,$SeeIfUserExist);
       $CheckIfRowDataExist = mysqli_num_rows($SqlQueryUserCheck);


       //ToCreateDataBaseAndUser
       if($CheckIfRowDataExist < 1){
         $InsertDataBaseIntel ="INSERT INTO database_users(email,check_if_created) VALUES ('$UserEmail','$MysqlUserDataBaseCreate');";
         mysqli_query($conn,$InsertDataBaseIntel);
         $CreateDataBaseForUser ="CREATE DATABASE $MysqlUserDataBaseCreate ;";
         mysqli_query($conn,$CreateDataBaseForUser);

       }else{
         echo 'you are restrictd to one database';
       }


       ?>
   ```

Comment: You shouldn't even have a table per user, let alone a database - just use one table for all users. Also, you should look into [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), as your code is currently **vulnerable** to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Finally, ensure your DB user only has the [**required privileges**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). You can refer to [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) for further information on how to prevent SQL injection in PHP :)

Comment: My objective is to create  script that could be used for a hosting company. This is why I am allowing the users to create a database.

Comment: Everything about this code is **extremely dangerous**. If you're intending to deploy this you have a lot of work to do to ensure this can't be used maliciously. Security is not something you can bolt on top. It **must** be considered at every single level.

Comment: I am not intending to use this it is just for practice.